# Creating list of list from row of others matrix

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to create list from existing matrix:

```
a = matrix([[    0,     0,     0, ...,    82,   140,   165],
        [    0,     0,     0, ..., 30925, 30830, 27075],
        [    0,     0,     0, ...,   628,   678,   528],
        ...,
        [    0,     0,     0, ...,   988,   930,   878],
        [    0,     1,     0, ..., 21140, 24720, 22681],
        [    0,     0,     0, ...,  1809,  1655,  1560]])

b = matrix([[   0,    0,    0, ...,   26,   18,   14],
        [   0,    0,    0, ..., 1473, 1005,  904],
        [   0,    0,    0, ...,  138,   61,   72],
        ...,
        [   0,    0,    0, ...,   21,   18,   21],
        [   0,    0,    0, ..., 1036,  921,  670],
        [   0,    0,    0, ...,  176,  357,  204]])

c = matrix([[    0,     0,     0, ...,    89,    64,    78],
        [    0,     0,     0, ..., 16346, 11977, 10209],
        [    0,     0,     0, ...,   678,   890,  1013],
        ...,
        [    0,     0,     0, ...,   926,  1622,  1922],
        [    0,     0,     0, ...,  5744,  6704,  9143],
        [    0,     0,     0, ...,     7,     9,     2]])
```

`a.shape`

(13, 136)

`b.shape`

(13, 136)

`c.shape`

(13, 136)

**expected output**: I would like to create a list of list like that

```
[ [a[0],b[0],c[0]], ... , [a[n],b[n],c[n]] ]
```

example with first and last row of each matrix:

```
[ [[ 0, 0, 0, ..., 82, 140, 165],[ 0, 0, 0, ..., 26, 18, 14],[ 0, 0, 0, ..., 89, 64, 78]] , ... ,[[ 0, 0, 0, ..., 1809, 1655, 1560],[ 0, 0, 0, ..., 176, 357, 204], [ 0, 0, 0, ..., 7, 9, 2]] ]
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `list(zip(a, b, c))`?

Comment: @timgeb : if I'm not mistaken, your answer returns me list of matrix. My output is like an append function : 
my_list = ['geeks', 'for', 'geeks'] 
another_list = [6, 0, 4, 1] 
my_list.append(another_list) 
print my_list

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then. With small datastructures that we can copy and paste.

Comment: @timgeb ok, thanks for your help i will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3],
              [12, 9, 0],
              [2, 45, 2]])

b = np.matrix([[12, 9, 0],
              [2, 67, 94],
              [2, 45, 2]])
x = [list(t) for t in zip(a.tolist(),b.tolist())]
print(x)

Out:
[[[1, 2, 3], [12, 9, 0]], [[12, 9, 0], [2, 67, 94]], [[2, 45, 2], [2, 45, 2]]]
```

Comment: Thank for your help !! it works great with multiple matrix too.